# Suppose that $f$ has the property that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Tags: analysis

I am given the assumption that a function $f$ has the property that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. I am wondering if it follows that $f(x-y)=f(x)-f(y)$. I think that this is false, yet I see this being used in proofs.

Comment: Of course it's true.  f(x-y)+f (y)=f (x).  It's also true that f (q)=qf (1) for all rational q.

Comment: Your condition is the definition of $f$ being a group homomorphism for addition. Your question is the sort of thing that would be treated as an exercise in chapter one of a group theory textbook: for a group homomorphism $f$, we always have $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 7):

We have $f(x-y)+f(y)=f((x-y)+y)$.